# How to downgrade mono 3.12.1 to 3.0.0?

Tags: mono

I got exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'system.Windows.Forms, Version =3.5.0.0 ...
```

I think that mono version 3.0.0 can solve the problem but I can't downgrade the version.

Comment: Ubunto 16.04...

Comment: Is it mongodb or mono what is mono first of all????

Comment: I installed from the site for the first time
Then I installed script from a forum to downgrade to 3.12.1 and i want to downgrade to 3.0.0 Hope this solves the exception

Comment: You haven't told the *exact procedure* you followed to install 3.12.1.